# IPhone Video Tracking App

Tags: iphone, video, download

I plan to develop an IPhone app but I am newbie to Iphone development and wonder if it can be done or not before I get my hands on it.

The will be a kind of special browser which can run any site but it will be activated on those site which plays audio/video somehow. Let's say they open up MyVideoSite.com in my app. The website has many flash videos and can app download the video without knowing URL or anything? Say the object on the page is youtube embedded code or if not youtube but similar.

I just need to make sure if the app can act as a sandbox for audio/video sites so it can download audio/videos from websites anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to scan the page for video content and download those videos.

Here is one way to do it:

- Write a generic parser looking for video content, and specific parsers for popular sites where your generic parser is not enough.
- Then you have to download the video, which is easier if the video is just a file on the server, and it's not so easier if you have to download in streaming. You can handle the second case using ffmpeg for your app and do something like

```
    ffmpeg -y -i http://url-to-the-video-stream -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 432x240 -vcodec libx264 -b 512k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 0 -refs 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 512k -bufsize 512k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 30 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 432:240 -g 30 -async 2 result-iphone.ts
```

FFMPEG uses the GPL license but as long as the binary is not combined into your program you don't have to distribute your source. See http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem

Comment: I have heard IPhone can't play flash videos and I wonder how it plays youtube videos then? Is that its own player which replace flash player behind the scene?

Comment: Yes, iOS devices use their own player. The video stored in youtube is h.264, not flash. FFMPEG is able to convert FLV to MP4 but that won't happen in real time in iOS.

Comment: Can I know actually what does happen behind the scene? How Apple video player actually works?

Comment: There is nothing special to know. The player receives video from youtube coded in h.264 and plays it. You can create your own player using the classes MPMoviePlayerController (from MediaPlayer.framework) or AVPlayer (from AVFoundation.framework).

Comment: OK perfect. Say youtube video is encoded in h.264 but many other site's videos can be encoded in different format. Can FFMPEG handle all these formats?

Comment: Yes, it can handle most formats. You can install macports, then `sudo port install ffmpeg` and try the command above from your terminal.